# how to make other elements to react the pressing the button in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have and simple example of the shiny app. Here I am testing the reaction of other elements to the change in the specific element.

**ui.r**

```
 library(shiny)
 shinyUI(fluidPage(

  titlePanel("SCORE CARD DEVELOPMENT PLATFORM"),
    navbarPage("ScoreDevApp",
         tabPanel("Settings",
                  fluidRow(column(2,
                                   actionButton("goButton_service", "Load    saved parameters",width=200)
                                  ,radioButtons("DB_switch"
                                              , "Select Data Source"
                                              ,c("Oracle"=1,"text file"=2)
                                  )
                  )             
                  )
         ),
         tabPanel("Download & Binning input data",
                  fluidRow(column(2,
                                  textInput("text","test")))),
         id="ScoreDevApp"
    )
  )
)
```

**server.r**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)


shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

observeEvent(input$goButton_service, {
  updateRadioButtons(session
                   , "DB_switch"
                   , "Select Data Source"
                   ,c("Oracle"=1,"text file"=2)
                   , selected = 2
                   , inline = FALSE
  )
  if(input$DB_switch==2){
    updateTextInput(session,text,"test",value="testing")
   }

  })  
})
```

Pressing the button 'goButton_service' causes the update of radiobutton 'DB_switch' -> selected item is 2 in place of 1 (on default). Thats is done well.

But then I am going to check the value of radiobutton: if it is 2 then the string "testing" should have been passed to the textInput 'text' on the tabpanel 'Download & Binning input data'. However it is not performed. Need a help with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the version below (I have removed the enable/disable code, it had no function). Your main error were the missing quotes around `text`.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)


shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  observe({
    if (input$DB_switch == "2") {
      updateTextInput(session, "text", value = "testing")
    }
  }
  )
  observeEvent(input$goButton_service, {
    updateRadioButtons(session
                       , "DB_switch"
                       , "Select Data Source"
                       ,c("Oracle"=1,"text file"=2)
                       , selected = 2
                       , inline = FALSE
    )
  })
})
```

Comment: I have tried your version but it is no use. I have tried the option with no quaotes in your script "(if (input$DB_switch == "2") ". Have you had supposed results (after pressing the button string "testing" should appear in the textInput 'text')?

Comment: Well, I have found the discrepancy in your script and have removed it. To make your script work you need to write 'selected = "2" ' but not ' selected = 2'. After the correction it works well.

Answer (score 0):

If you update `textInput` twice, as in the example below, it should solve your problem

---

### Server

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  observeEvent(input$goButton_service, {
    updateRadioButtons(session, "goButton_service", selected = 2)
    updateTextInput(session, "text", "test", value = "testing")
  }) 

  observe({
    if (input$DB_switch == 2) 
      updateTextInput(session, "text", "test", value = "testing")
  })

})
```

Comment: well, it is appeared to generate the necessary output if to correct the element id and label. But I need the output according to steps as follows:
press 'goButton_service' ->change radiobutton - > depending on the updated value of radiobutton to pass the string to textinput 'text'.
Your proposal is to pass the string upon the pressing the button (it looks like).